# DNS A records Ubuntu server

Tags: server, apache2, bind

This may sounds very easy to do but I'm a little confused in the process. I've registered a domain e.g. example.com and want to point it to my server with IP e.g. 111.111.111.111

I've made ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com at my domain control panel but how do I add the -A records at the server end (Ubuntu).

Do I need to install bind or it can be done without it?

Answer (score 1):

You generally don't need to install BIND. You generally use the registrar's (web-based) tools to configure the registrar's nameserver such that it includes A and other records for your domain.